# Как сформулировать вывод из SQLite3 в массив типа const char *list[]?

Tags: c, sqlite3

Ну собственно вопрос. Вот такой код, он, как видно, добывает из таблицы данные, `list.c`:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libintl.h>

int list_cb_1(void *, int, char **, char **);

int list_cb_2(void *count, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    
    int *c = count;
    
    *c = atoi(argv[0]);
    
    return 0;
    
}

int list(void)
{

    sqlite3 *db;
    
    char *err_msg = 0;

    char sql[100];

    int count = 0;

    int rc = sqlite3_open("plants.db", &db);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {

        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", 
        sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return 1;
    }

    sprintf(sql, "SELECT id, number, familia, taxon FROM numbers");

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, list_cb_1, 0, &err_msg);

    sprintf(sql, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers");

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, list_cb_2, &count, &err_msg);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK )
    {

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to select data\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);

        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return 1;
    }

    printf("\n---------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Total Numbers: %d\n", count);

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}

int list_cb_1(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{

    NotUsed = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {

        printf("%s\t ", argv[i]);

    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Это вызов в `report.c`:

```
const char *report_1 (void)
{

    list();

}

...

HPDF_Page_ShowText (page, report_1());
```

Comment: Насколько я понял вывод гугла по запросу `sqlite3_exec` вам надо передать в нее четвертым аргументом (это тот `void *`, что передается первым в callback) адрес какой-то такой `struct reqresult { size_t n_rows, char **list;}` структуры, в элемент `list` которой, вы будете добавлять (динамически, вызывая realloc) копии argv[], передаваемых в callback.

Comment: @avp, ну теперь я ещё больше запутался :))

Comment: Вот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1806740/7286264), который печатает результат sql запроса (printf в цикле). Вот [тут](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) сказано, что callback может вызываться несколько раз, получая очередную порцию sql результата. Остается собрать все эти сроки, передаваемые в callback в единый список (можно его реализовать как массив указателей в динамической памяти).  Перед вызовом вы инициализируете .n_rows в этом заголовке нулем. При каждом вызове callback должен добавлять туда argc новых строк из argv

Comment: @avp, так ведь и у меня печатает в цикле. Только нужно не printf, а в массив. А как реализовать сие, я не соображу, в связи с этим и настоящий вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

У меня нет sqllite, поэтому не проверял, но думаю, вам надо написать какой-то такой callback:
(я предполагаю, что при каждом вызове он получает очередную строку вывода sql-запроса, в параметре `argc` передается количество колонок, в `argv` их значения, а в `azColName` их названия)

```
struct sqlres {  // структура, которую запоняет callback
  size_t n_rows,
    n_cols;
  char **col_names;
  char ***list;
};

// вспомогательные функции
static void
copy_strings (char **dst, char **src, int n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    dst[i] = strdup(src[i]);
}

static void
free_strings (char **a, int n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    free(a[i]);
}

void
free_sqlres (struct sqlres *p)
{
  if (p->col_names) {
    free_strings(p->col_names, p->n_cols);
    free(p->col_names);
  }
  if (p->list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p->n_rows; i++) {
      free_strings(p->list[i], p->n_cols);
      free(p->list[i]);
    }
    free(p->list);
  }
  memset(p, 0, sizeof(*p));
}

// callback
int
list_cb_2(void *p, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
  struct sqlres *r = (struct sqlres *)p;

  if (r->n_rows == 0) { // fill only on first call
    r->n_cols = argc;
    r->col_names = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));
    copy_strings(r->col_names, azColName, argc);
  }

  r->list = realloc(r->list, sizeof(void *) * (r->n_rows + 1));
  r->list[r->n_rows] = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));
  copy_strings(r->list[r->n_rows], argv, argc);
  
  r->n_rows++;

  return 0;
}
```

И вызывать его так:

```
 struct sqlres sr = {0, 0, 0, 0};  // init result list data header

   ....

 rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, list_cb_2, &sr, &err_msg);

   ....
 // print sql result
 // print columns title
 for (int i = 0; i < sr.n_cols; i++)
   printf("| %s ", s.col_names[i]);
 puts("\n-----------------");

 // print columns values
 for (int i = 0; i < sr.n_rows; i++) {
   char **as = sr.list[i];
   for (int j = 0; j < sr.n_cols; j++) 
     printf("| %s ", as[j]);
   puts("");  // need if last value not have '\n'
 }
   ...
 free_sqlres(&sr);
   ...
```

Comment: Кто-то минусанул, неужели не вышло :) Я сейчас попробую, авось осилю. Спасибо.

Comment: К сожалению, не смог приспособить под свою задачу, но здесь ещё сказывается мой весьма низкий уровень владения C.

Comment: Сейчас кину в update законченный пример аналогичнго callback с main (но без sql, которого у меня нет). Можете поиграться с ним, если что-то непонятно.

Comment: //// только сейчас пришло в голову, что видимо я ошибался с интерпретацией аргументов callback. Скорее  один вызов это **одна строка** результата, а  элементы argv это данные из разных колонок. Для такого формата напишу какое-то решение завтра (если время будет)

Comment: Да, да, argv это они самые)))

Comment: Написал новую версию (насколько догадываюсь о форме передачи данных в callback)

Comment: @Max, если будете пробовать новый вариант, напишите в комменте, работает или нет?

Comment: да, безусловно, я отпишусь.

Comment: @Max, еще не пробовали?